# How to delet from object by index?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have object `edited`:

[image]

When I try to delete element from object by `i` where `i` is `0`:

```
delete edited[i]
```

Then I do `console.log(edited)` and see instead deleted elements - undefined:

[image]

How to get clear output object `edited`?

Comment: You have an array. Use splice.

Comment: `delete` leaves holes in array... splice() doesn't

Comment: Can you share sample for my case?

Comment: `splice(startIndex, count)` ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: How to get start index?

Comment: that is your `i` ....`edited.splice(i , 1)`

Comment: ou are wrong: (1, i)

Comment: This code would start at array index 1 (the "2nd" element, since it's zero-indexed) and delete ```i``` elements from it. @charlietfl was correct. It should be ```edited.splice(i, 1)```, which will start at index ```i``` and remove ```1``` element.